# Flex: 1st and 2nd same width, 3th Item full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this HTML & CSS Code.

I would like that:

First label and second label equal size,
third label should be full width.

This should then give:

[image]

I have been playing around with flex and the possible options.
I have watched tutorials and read specifications, but for some reason I'm unable to get this working in a simple manner.

Here you can find my html and css:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@400;800&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flow-root;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    /* background-image: url(../images/background-cars.jpg); */
    background-size: cover ;
    min-height: (1vh-1em);
    background-color: saddlebrown;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}


input,
select,
button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 15px;
}

input,
select{
    color: gray;
}

/* flex */
fieldset{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1em;
}

label{
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

/* layout */

form {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

button{
    background-color: gold;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

h1{
    color: gold;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

legend{
    font-weight: 800;
}

fieldset{
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Boo! Ka Car.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main copy.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <form id="form1" action="mailto:naam@domein.be?subject=Booking&ampm" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>DATE &amp; TIME</legend>
            <label>
                PICKUP DATE
                <input type="date">
            </label>
            <label>
                HOUR
                <input type="number" min="1" max="12">
            </label>
            <label>
                AM/PM
                <select name="ampm" id="amAndpm">
                    <option value="am">AM</option>
                    <option value="pm">PM</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" form="form1" value="BOOKNOW">BOOK NOW</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@400;800&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flow-root;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    /* background-image: url(../images/background-cars.jpg); */
    background-size: cover ;
    min-height: (1vh-1em);
    background-color: saddlebrown;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}


input,
select,
button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 15px;
}

input,
select{
    color: gray;
}

/* flex */
fieldset{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1em;
}

label{
    flex: 1 1 0;
    flex-basis: unset;
}

/* layout */

form {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

button{
    background-color: gold;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

h1{
    color: gold;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

legend{
    font-weight: 800;
}

fieldset{
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Boo! Ka Car.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main copy.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <form id="form1" action="mailto:naam@domein.be?subject=Booking&ampm" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>DATE &amp; TIME</legend>
            <label>
                PICKUP DATE
                <input type="date">
            </label>
            <label>
                HOUR
                <input type="number" min="1" max="12">
            </label>
            <label>
                AM/PM
                <select name="ampm" id="amAndpm">
                    <option value="am">AM</option>
                    <option value="pm">PM</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" form="form1" value="BOOKNOW">BOOK NOW</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your answer is very close to the solution.
Could you please explain how flex-basis: unset; helps?

Comment: @Nomistake Default value of flex-basis is auto. The length is equal to the length of the flexible item. If the item has no length specified, the length will be according to its content.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the heights of the input field to your liking, for the code below, it's just their naturally inherent heights.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat+Alternates:wght@400;800&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flow-root;
    font-family: 'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
    /* background-image: url(../images/background-cars.jpg); */
    background-size: cover ;
    min-height: (1vh-1em);
    background-color: saddlebrown;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}


input,
select,
button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 15px;
}

input,
select{
    color: gray;
}

/* flex */
fieldset{
    gap: 1em;
}

label{
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

/* layout */

form {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}

button{
    background-color: gold;
    font-weight: 800;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

h1{
    color: gold;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

legend{
    font-weight: 800;
}

fieldset{
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.outer{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.inner{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.date{
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.hour{
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Boo! Ka Car.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main copy.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <form id="form1" action="mailto:naam@domein.be?subject=Booking&ampm" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>DATE &amp; TIME</legend>
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="inner">
                <div class="date">
                    PICKUP DATE
                    <input type="date">
                </div>
                <div class="hour">
                    HOUR
                    <input type="number" min="1" max="12" class="hour">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                  AM/PM
                  <select name="ampm" id="amAndpm">
                      <option value="am">AM</option>
                      <option value="pm">PM</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
            <div>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" form="form1" value="BOOKNOW">BOOK NOW</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are using a grid i see... I would like to use only Flex

Comment: Oh in that case you could add display: flex;, flex-direction:row; to the inner div and remove the grid related attributes in it. Then for both the date and hour divs in inner, give it an attribute of flex:1, and give the date div a margin-right of whatever separation you want between the date and hour divs. I've edited the code given above to use just flex if you wanted to take a look at that.